Polynomial multiplication of "Extension fields" from cryptography
I am implementing the "AES" (Advanced Encryption Algorithm) in Rust,
For it i'm creating the polynomial multiplication required in "extension_fields" or "galois_fields" with "no prime order". (This operation yet hasn't implemented the "modular operation" for multiplication , because i still testing, so don't worry for it).
Such polynomial consist of : (exponents and coefficients)
--The index of the element is equivalent to his exponent,
--The actual value is equal to the coefficient
[  1   ,  1   ,  1   , 1,1,1,1 , 0   ]
1x⁰ + 1x¹ +  1x² +   ...  + 0x⁷
This is the Actual Code :
#![allow(warnings)]
struct polynomial(Vec<u8>);

impl polynomial{
    fn mult(&self , y : &Self) -> Vec<u8> {
        let x = match self { Self(val) => val }; //get the vector
        let y = match y { Self(val) => val }; // get the vector

        const vecs_len : usize = 31 ; //max bit of u16 = 2¹⁵ ; 2¹⁵ * 2¹⁵ = 2³⁰ => (len = 31)

        let mut poly_1 : [u8;vecs_len] = [0;vecs_len]; //slice to allocate the coefficients
        let mut poly_2 : [u8;vecs_len] = [0;vecs_len]; //slice to allocate the coefficients

        let mut polys : Vec< [u8;vecs_len] > = Vec::new();
        //polys will be appened with the polys_{n} vectors
        //and it will be returned
        
        let mut elm_1 : u8 = 0 ;//element 1 from "x"
        let mut elm_2 : u8 = 0 ;//element 2 from "x"

        
        for e in 0..x.len(){
            if e % 2 == 0 {
                //This code is supose to get 2 elem.'s (by iteration) from "x", 
                //and multiply it by all the coefficients in "y",
                //and the result of it (a slice) , is pushed into the polys vector
            
                elm_1 = x[e];  
                elm_2 = x[e + 1]; 

                if elm_1 != 0 || elm_2 != 0{
                    //multiply the "x" elements by all the "y" coefficients
                    for f in 0..y.len() {
                        let mut yln  = y[f];

                        let val_1 = elm_1 * yln ; 
                        let val_2 = elm_2 * yln ;

                        poly_1[f + e] = val_1;
                        poly_2[f + e + 1] = val_2;
                    }
                }
                //push the the 2 slices into polys
                polys.push(poly_1);
                polys.push(poly_2);
            }
        }// loop
        
        while true{

            let mut multy : [u8;vecs_len] = [0;vecs_len] ;
            //variable to have the resultant sum from the similr terms
            
            if polys[0] != [0;vecs_len] && polys[1] == [0;vecs_len]{
                multy = polys[0].clone();

            }else if polys[1] != [0;vecs_len] && polys[0] == [0;vecs_len] {
                multy = polys[1].clone();
            }
            
            
            for e in 0..vecs_len {
                let elm_1 : u8 = polys[0][e];
                let elm_2 : u8 = polys[1][e];

                let elm = (elm_1 + elm_2) % 2 ;
                multy[e] = elm;
            }
        

            polys.push(multy);
            polys.remove(0);
            polys.remove(1);
            
            if polys.len() < 2 {break;}
        } //while

        let res = polys[0].to_vec();
        return res ;

    } //fn mult
}
fn main(){

    let f = polynomial::new(1).unwrap();
    let g = polynomial::new(1).unwrap();
    let p = f.mult(&g);

    println!("f: {f:?}");
    println!("g: {g:?}");
    println!("p: {p:?}");

 }

The function "Polynomial::new()" creates the polynomial representation of a number.
This is the binary result:
f: polynomial([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
g: polynomial([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
p: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Though it has no sense.
Regarding that this is an polynomial multiplication , and remembering that x¹ * x² = x³
i should get something like this :
[1, 0, 0 ,0 ... , 0]

There are quite a few things wrong here.  I suggest you break it down into smaller functions, and write unit tests for each.  That will help to identify where the logic isn't meeting your expectations.  Then you can ask smaller, more focused questions on those specific issues.
